# Converting string in '[hh]:mm:ss' format to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion

I am managing a data frame in python that has one column with durations of incidents. The type of the original data frame is a string and I want to convert to DateTime.

The problem is that the format of the string is '**[hh]:mm: ss**', that means that if the duration its more than 24 hours do not count in days but in hours. Example:

```
>>> df
   duration Location
0  00:01:30        a
1  12:12:04        b
2  26:45:05        c
3  45:01:12        d
```

I'm trying with different formats but does not work:

```
df['Duration'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Duracion'], format='%[H]:%M:%S')
```

Any help?

Comment: What happens?  Do you get an error?  Or could you post an example of bad output and the desired output?

Comment: a get:  `ValueError: '%' is a bad directive in format '%[H]:%M:%S'`

Answer (score 2):

Try `pandas.to_timedelta`:

```py
df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.